# Title pages in R-markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, page-title

I am having some trouble creating a title page in R-markdown. IAfter some internet searching, I have tried this:

```
---
title: "PDS Job Survey Report"
author: \centering{Adam Sokol\ Office of Assessment and Accreditation\ University of South Carolina}
output: word_document
---
\newpage
\maketitle
```

Here is what I would like it to look like:

PDS Job Survey Repor
Adam Sokol
Office of Assessment
University of South Carolina

Centered under the title. Please Help!

Comment: Remove all the LaTeX commands (`\centering...` and so on).